# Ruby enumerable reset?

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble understanding exactly how much state a ruby enumerable keeps.
I know some python, so I was expecting that after I take an item from an enumerable, it's gone and the next item will be returned as I take another item.
Strangely, this does happen when I use `next` but not when I use anything like `take` of `first`.
Here's an example:

```
a = [1,2,3].to_enum
# => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>
a.take(2)
# => [1, 2]
a.next
# => 1
a.next
# => 2
a.take(2)
# => [1, 2]
a.next
# => 3
a.next
# StopIteration: iteration reached an end
#        from (irb):58:in `next'
#        from (irb):58
#        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
a.take(2)
# => [1, 2]
```

It seems like the enumerable keeps state between `next` calls, but resets before each `take` call?

Comment: Please [read this](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10534)

Comment: Then read again,,, there is answer. **Note that +next+ does not affect other non-external enumeration methods unless underlying iteration method itself has side-effect, e.g.IO#each_line.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a little confusing, but it's important to note that in Ruby there is the [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html) class and the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html) module.

The `Enumerator` class includes `Enumerable` (like most of enumerable objects such as `Array`, `Hash`, etc.

The [`next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) method is provided as part of the `Enumerator`, which indeed has an internal state. You can consider an `Enumerator` very close to the concept of `Iterator` exposed by other languages.

When you instantiate the Enumerator, the internal pointer points to the first item in the collection.

```
2.1.5 :021 > a = [1,2,3].to_enum
 => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each>
2.1.5 :022 > a.next
 => 1
2.1.5 :023 > a.next
 => 2
```

This is not the only purpose of the Enumerator (otherwise it would probably be called `Iterator`). However, this is one of the documented feature.

> An Enumerator can also be used as an external iterator. For example, #next returns the next value of the iterator or raises StopIteration if the Enumerator is at the end.
>
> ```
> e = [1,2,3].each   # returns an enumerator object.
> puts e.next   # => 1
> puts e.next   # => 2
> puts e.next   # => 3
> puts e.next   # raises StopIteration
> ```

But as I said before, the `Enumerator` class includes `Enumerable`. It means every instance of an `Enumerator` exposes the `Enumerable` methods that are designed to work on a collection. In this case, the collection is the one the `Enumerator` is wrapped on.

[`take`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-take) is a generic `Enumerable` method. It is designed to return the first N elements from `enum`. It's important to note that `enum` is referring to any generic class that includes `Enumerable`, not to the `Enumerator`. Therefore, `take(2)` will returns the first two elements of the collection, regardless the position of the pointer inside the `Enumerator` instance.

Let me show you a practical example. I can create a custom class, and implement `Enumerable`.

```
class Example
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(array)
    @array = array
  end

  def each(*args, &block)
    @array.each(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

I can mix `Enumerable`, and as long as I provide an implementation for `each` I get all the other methods for free, including `take`.

```
e = Example.new([1, 2, 3])
 => #<Example:0x007fa9529be760 @array=[1, 2, 3]>
e.take(2)
 => [1, 2]
```

As expected, `take` returns the first 2 elements. `take` ignores anything else of my implementation, exactly as in `Enumerable`, including states or pointers.

Comment: I see, I had no idea that everything on enumerable depended only on `each`. Thank you. small follow-up: then the only way to take the first item from an enumerable, store it in a variable and then operate on the remaining items would be something like the following?
`val = enum.first; res =  enum.drop(1).map { |i| i * 2 }`

Comment: No. You can use a slice with range. `[1,2,3,4].to_enum.to_a[1..-1]` to only get the portion of the items you want.

Answer (score 2):

Per the documentation, `Enumerable#take` returns first n elements from the Enumerator, not the next n elements from the cursor. Only the methods from [Enumerator](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerator.html) are going to operate on that internal cursor; the Enumerable mix-in is just a collection of methods for enumerating which don't necessarily share cursors.

If you wanted, you could implement Enumerator#take to do what you expect:

```
class Enumerator
  def take(n = 1)
    n.times.map { self.next }
  end
end
```